# Ajax call not working on public Dog API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use the public dog API: https://dog.ceo/dog-api/ .It is working with postman, curl and on browser but not able to call it using AJAX.
Anyone please provide inputs what I am doing wrong here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data){console.log(data)},
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the response type is JSON, hence you need to set `dataType: 'json'`, not `script`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's because that domain does not return CORS headers in the response, so you will not be able to make the call to it from client-side JS.

Comment: can i pass in ajaxx `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: No, that header has to come *from* the server. There is absolutely nothing that can be done in JS to fix this issue.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You have `dataType: 'script'` change it to `json` because api is returning response in `json`

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){console.log(data)},
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```